# Event target in IE8 in Image.onload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

In my image's `onLoad` event handler I need to fetch the URL of the image that fired the event. In IE8 the value of `window.event.srcElement` is always `null`. Is there a workaround?

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function (e) {
    var v = e || window.event;
    var t = v.target || v.srcElement;
    // t is null here
    //...
};
image.src = "test.png";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `this`. `this` in an event handler is the element on which the event is attached.

```
image.onload = function() {
    var t = this;
    alert(t);
};
```